# Java - printing unique number sequences

Tags: java, loops, class

I have been trying to find a way to print an inverted pyramid that has a certain number sequence.  The sequence needed is as follows as well as what I currently have.

The prompt asked to write a method that takes two numbers and create an inverted pyramid with the first row having a length of the first integer and starting with the number entered second.  Then only have the sequence start at 1 after 9 is reached.

```
    Needed:                Currently Have:

    1 2 4 7 2 7 4              1 2 3 4 5 6 7
      3 5 8 3 8 5                8 9 1 2 3 4
        6 9 4 9 6                  5 6 7 8 9
          1 5 1 7                    1 2 3 4
            6 2 8                      5 6 7
              3 9                        8 9
                1                          1



    static int plotTriangle(int a, int b){

        int num = b;

        for (int row = a; row >= 0; row--){

            for (int i = a; i - row >= 0; i--){
                System.out.print("  ");
                num += (num+a-row);
                num -= 2;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++){
                num++;
                while (num >= 10){
                    num -= 9;
                }                
                System.out.print(num + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter length: ");
        int l = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Start: ");
        int s = in.nextInt();

        int triangle = plotTriangle(l, s);
    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: It was how do i get the desired number pattern to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int length = 7;

        int[][] numbers = new int[length][length];

        int count = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < (i+1); ++j) {
                numbers[i][j] = count++;
                if(count > 9)
                    count = 1;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; ++j) {
                if(numbers[j][i] == 0)
                    System.out.print(" ");
                else
                    System.out.print(numbers[j][i]);
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

This will give you your result. Note that I didn't include the dynamic part with the scanner. I used the length and the start-number as constants.

Explanation: 
In the first loop I am basically just storing the numbers in an array. And in the second loop this array is printed in a different order.